# zmin axis value for a 3d plot in TikZ

Tags: pgfplots

If I plot this the z axis does not start at 0 but somwhere negative. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
colormap={whitered}{
color(0cm)=(white);
color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
%axis equal,
colormap name=whitered,
width=20cm,
view={340}{25},
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
%domain=-10:1,
%y domain=-1:1,
samples=41, %57 
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$z$,
zmin=0.0,
yticklabels={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
%zticklabels={,,},
]

\addplot3[thick, draw=red, mark=*, fill=orange, opacity=0.2] coordinates {(1,1,0)(-1,1,0)(-1,-1,0)(1,-1,0)(1,1,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is due to your sample data: If you look in the `.log` file, you'll see the warning `Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis z is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.0:0.0]) on input line 37.` Try changing the first coordinate in your data to `(1,1,1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Jake provided the reason for this behaviour in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194680/zmin-axis-value-for-a-3d-plot-in-tikz/194681#comment450169_194680). A quick fix is to specify `zmax` for the `axis` as well, e.g. `zmax=1`.